# How to calculate the rank in mysql

Tags: mysql

I need to calculate the rank in mysql. Suppose I have list of sum of my product sales values of entire month then i need to rank the product from highest sales value in order to rank like 1 ,2 ,3 etc

```
Month  Product  Sum of Sales

Jan     Latop       450000
jan     Latop       150000
Jan     Latop       250000
Feb     Desktop     200000
Feb     Desktop     150000
Feb     Desktop     180000
```

so from above data output will be like

Month  Product  Sum of Sales  rank

```
Jan     Latop       450000  1
Jan     Latop       250000  2
jan     Latop       150000  3
Feb     Desktop     200000  1
Feb     Desktop     180000  2
Feb     Desktop     150000  3
```

Comment: totally not clear. Where are data? Wanted behaviour? What is your attempt?

Comment: i have put the data above but its converted into text format, i just wat to use the rank function which is not available in mysql

Comment: How would you handle ties? What would the desired result look like? And see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: this is one of the most frequently asked questions for `mysql` tag

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Rank function in MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3333665/rank-function-in-mysql)

Comment: Post your query which calculates this sum

Comment: sdesh as @newtover pointed out it's duplicate question. Look here for ready answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/25763224/330242 What you need is ranking over partition

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
SELECT month,product,sumOfSales, @curRank := @curRank + 1 AS rank
FROM products p, (
SELECT @curRank := 0
) q
ORDER BY sumOfSales DESC;
```

I am assuming the table name is `product` and column name is `sumOfSales`.

Answer (score -1):

You Can use this Query
**SELECT sales FROM TABLE Order by sales DESC**
sales is your column name where sum of sale is stored 
Query Will Return Record with most sales first and so on.

Comment: i want to calculate the rank of hightest sales to lowest sales from 1, 2 , 3 etc